# AWS Security group for RDS - Inbound rules

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-security-group

I created a MySQL instance in AWS RDS and selected the create new security group option which created a new security group as below

[Inbound rule created with a specific allowed ip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPVGs.png)

This allows traffic from only the specified ip. In the public accessibility option I have selected yes.
Now, I am able to connect to this database on my local computer. I am not able to understand the point of this security group inbound rule and where this ip in inbound rule is coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your public IP (at least for now). /32 is from CIDR, means that this is only one ip in this network (SG work with CIDT, not just IP).

So, RDS could be accessed only from you IP

Comment: ok, so if I change my ip, say start a vpn, then I won't be able to connect to the db?

Comment: Correct. Please, don't open your RDS to any internet ip (0.0.0.0/0 CIDR) because it's not safe. It's fast, but your RDS could be attacked